# Dealing with images using Node.JS

Tags: node.js

I am New to NodeJS enviornment

- I am trying to use the Image stored in server in android client
- Usually we generate a JSON for data(Non,image) in the server using
  `JSON.stringify`

I am successful for retrieving data from MySQL table and converting into a JSON using the program below

```
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'test_programs_database'
});

http.createServer(function (request, response) 
{ 
        console.log('Creating the http server');
        connection.query('SELECT id, content FROM test WHERE id IN (1, 2)', function(err, rows, fields)
        {
                console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                console.log('no of records is '+rows.length);
                response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
                response.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
                //response.end();
        }); 

}).listen(8084);
```

**How to deal with Images stored in Database of server using NodeJS ?**
*Any good links to learning material to help me understand this will be helpful*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a common way is to return the image URL in the JSON payload.
if the image data itself is stored in the database, create another endpoint to your API that returns the image data (eg: `http://www.example.com/images/my_image.jpg`)

sending only the image URL to the Android client rather than the image data itself will also allow you to cache the images locally